Marketplace in future desert world
I'm creating a desert world in the distant future. The sun has expanded, making it closer to Earth and drying out much of the planet. Civilization is back to nomadic and or early civilization types of lifestyles. I want there to be a marketplace in this desert world.
How similar do you think it would be to marketplaces in the desert today? Are there any things you think I should include or exclude?

Hello @EileenMatias, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. It's important that you read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], and [ask] to understand our limits. Such as (a) You're allowed one and only one question per post, (b) we don't answer open-ended questions, and (c) we don't answer story questions. Ignoring that the world drying out is a bit complicated because the water is all still there, whatever form such a market would take is entirely up to your story and not based on any story-independent world rule. What's stopping you from making a decision and moving on?

(1) What is a "marketplaces in the desert today"? If you mean cities such as Riadh or Timbuktu or even Alice Springs, then no, nothing even remotly resembling those existed in the times when the a nomadic lifestyle was the norm. (2) Making predictions about stuff happening a billion years in the future is heap difficult. The human species would be almost certainly have become extinct, for starters.

A marketplace happens when there is sufficient trade between groups on a regular basis.  A specific place for trade requires that a lot of trade has been happening first. Otherwise, trade simply happens when two groups meet or when a trader goes between groups.

When trade-routs cross.

Courtesy of our frenemy, ChatGPT, no copyright.
A northern settlement out of the desert trades with a southern - and a western trades with an eastern one. The trade-routs meet at an oasis.
The advantages to the traders are obvious, a source of life-saving water, a place to replenish food-stocks, camels for sale, goods traded can be bartered to ensure that the profits can be made in all four directions. It would lead to alliances, free-traders in-situ, adventurers and fugitives - all gathering and flowing through one place constantly. No passports, no questions asked.
If that oasis dries-up, then the venue is changed to another.

What is the uncanny image with grossly inconsistent shadows supposed to represent? I find the shadows pointing in random directions deeply disturbing.

Cosmology is a bit wacky there in AI land I'll grant you.
